# Is it possible to secure a single REST API for different data?

Tags: security, rest

I was asked this question in an interview as to, HOw would you secure REST API for different data? Say, I have a REST API URI of the form, http://domain.com/api/resources/products/productId.

Is it possible to secure this REST API for specific values of product ID? Say, for product IDs 1-10 can be allowed for any user, but product IDs above 10 cannot be accessed by anyone else other than an admin or in some cases, not accessible to anybody?

Can somebody help in answering this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is authorization - what is this user allowed to do.

There are many different ways of doing this. One possible way.

In your user table, have a list of IDs. Then compare this list with the requested ID and block users who do not have permission.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My question is what if an allowed ID is not allowed to access above a certain value of product ID in the API? Say, "user" is allowed to access the API but for values less than 10. How do we allow or deny the same user depending on data values? I can only think of checking the product ID value too before authorizing the request. But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I don't think there is another way than checking each ID individually. You could maybe add another column to the products, which you then use for authorization. This is probably better if you need to add another 'unprotected' ID later on.